# Web Drop-in integration "advanced use case" redirect result

Tags: adyen

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to retrieve the redirectResult when the user is redirected to our redirectUrl to invoke the /payment/details API endpoint to speed up delivering virtual goods instead of waiting for the web hook (I'm aware it will not work for "async" payment methods).

Looking at https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in/advanced-use-cases/redirect-result it should be possible, however, the returnUrl in CreateCheckoutSessionResponse returned from com.adyen.service.Checkout#sessions (adyen-java-api-library 17.2.0 - checkout api version v68) does not contain the aforementioned redirectResult param so the configuration we pass into the drop-in template is missing this data and does not seem to be available in the onPaymentCompleted callback either (only resultCode and sessionData).

```
@Override
public RedirectResponse handleRedirectToPartner(PaymentContext paymentContext) throws PartnerIntegrationException {
    final Payment payment = paymentContext.getPayment();

    final Amount amount = new Amount();
    amount.setCurrency(payment.getCurrency().toUpperCase());
    amount.setValue((long) payment.getPriceInCents());

    final CreateCheckoutSessionRequest checkoutSessionRequest = new CreateCheckoutSessionRequest();
    ...
    checkoutSessionRequest.setChannel(CreateCheckoutSessionRequest.ChannelEnum.WEB);
    checkoutSessionRequest.setReturnUrl(getReturnUrl());

    try {
        CreateCheckoutSessionResponse checkoutSessionResponse = checkout().sessions(checkoutSessionRequest);
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        params.put("environment", testMode ? "test" : "live");
        params.put("clientKey", adyenClientKey);
        JSONObject session = new JSONObject();
        session.put("id", checkoutSessionResponse.getId());
        session.put("sessionData", checkoutSessionResponse.getSessionData());
        params.put("session", session);
        params.put("urlKo", getFailureUrl());
        params.put("urlOk", checkoutSessionResponse.getReturnUrl());
        params.put("urlPending", getUrlPending(checkoutSessionResponse.getReturnUrl()));

        return new RedirectResponse(RedirectResponse.Type.REDIRECT_CUSTOM_HTML_ADYEN, null, params);
    } catch (ApiException | IOException e) {
        throw new PartnerIntegrationException("Failed creating Adyen session", e);
    }
}

protected Checkout checkout() {
    return new Checkout(new Client(adyenApiKey, testMode ? Environment.TEST : Environment.LIVE,
            testMode ? null : liveEndpointUrlPrefix));
}

(async () => {
    let configuration = ${partnerJsonParameters?string};
    configuration.onPaymentCompleted = function(result, component) {
        console.info(result);
        if (result.sessionData) {
            console.info(result.sessionData);
        }
        if (result.resultCode) {
            console.info(result.resultCode);
        }
        handleServerResponse(result, configuration);
    };
    configuration.onError = function(error, component) {
        console.error(error, component);
        handleServerResponse(result, configuration);
    };
    let checkout = await AdyenCheckout(configuration);
    checkout.create('dropin').mount('#dropin-container');
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sessions` request does not perform the payment, but only initiates the payment session with all required parameters and configuration.

The Web drop-in takes care of 'talking' to the Adyen backend and eventually, the payment outcome can be obtained **in the frontend** using the `onPaymentCompleted` handler.

```
  onPaymentCompleted: (result, component) => {
        console.info("onPaymentCompleted: " + result.resultCode);
        ...
      }
```

See [Use the result code](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in#get-payment-outcome)

On the server-side it is possible to get the payment result with a `/payments/details` call in addition to `/sessions` if needed.

```
 // get redirectResult appended to the returnUrl 
 String redirectResult = request.getParameter("redirectResult");

 var paymentDetails = new PaymentsDetailsRequest();
 paymentDetails.setDetails(Collections.singletonMap("redirectResult", redirectResult));

 // use paymentDetails() method
 var paymentsDetailsResponse = checkout.paymentsDetails(paymentDetails);

 String resultCode = paymentsDetailsResponse.getResultCode();
```

Note that a synchronous result is not always available, hence relying on the webhook is best.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve the payment result _before_ the AUTHORISATION webhook? We have seen long delays before the webhook is invoked for sync payment methods.

Comment: What I am hoping for is a way to retrieve the payment result when handling the Web drop-in return URL request on the server.

Comment: Hi Johno, I have updated the answer to add a sample code for the server-side processing

Comment: Thanks Beppe, that made sense however there is no redirectResult param available.

Comment: The only params I see in the onPaymentCompleted callback are resultCode and sessionData.. where can I retrieve redirectResult from?

Comment: Ah ok, I see, for a Credit Card payment there is no redirect so the parameter is never appended/available. You can get the resultCode on the front-end which is where you can decide what to do (ie show successful message to the shopper?)... but you want/need to initiate the `/payment/details` call anyway?

Comment: That's correct, since the previous Adyen payment integration provided this functionality we used it to provide immediate delivery of the virtual goods with no delay.

Comment: My colleague is currently testing out Adyen on the test environment with PAL enabled which may speed things up with the cost of receiving duplicate notifications.

Comment: Great, thanks for the update. The processing of the webhook is the recommended approach (we can look together at the delay or other issues if you like)

Answer (score 0):

I'm the (non-developer) colleague testing with PAL enable and sadly the delay is way too long with them as well. It is crucial for us to be able to get trustworthy authorisation and deliver the goods for the customers in (tens of) seconds, not minutes.

Is there any way to achieve fast and trustworthy credit card transactions with your web drop-in without notifications?

This is possible with your soon-to-be-obsoleted HPP integration and I find it unbelievable that you could have impaired, worsen the integration and user experience. So, there must be some kind of misunderstanding and communication breakdown somewhere (I hope). :)

Sorry, could not just comment as I don't have enough reputation...

Comment: Hi Ozz, I understand your issue and we will look into it. I propose you create a brand new question about the problem so it gets visibility and attention (better than an additional answer)